# Fixed Panel Grid moving on page scroll

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my jsf page i have a panelgrid(contains the dropdown, button as shown in

[fig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUAgw.png), In the header of a other panelgrid.
The problem is the when the page scrolls the first panelgrid is moving as shown below
[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOsnX.png) , how to resolve this?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and improve your question

Comment: Apologies, edited now hope its clear

Comment: Check again... still no code in [mcve] flavour